# Google Measurement Protocol Client ID Server Side

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

When my server gets a request via webservice i want to send a pageview hit to my google analytics.

Measurement Protocol requires a Client ID, in this case i want to set the server as id as client.

Should i just fake data like &cid=1 or there is any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client id is there to aggregate interactions into sessions and users. If you have no need to separate visits into different users you can generate a static client id and use that - you then will have only a single user which makes the reports look a bit strange, but as far as technology goes there is nothing wrong with simply using an random integer (the recommended format is UUID, but that's just to avoid situations where different users get the same id. This does not seem to be an issue).

However if your webservice users send along a token that is unique per user I suggest you use that (or rather a hash value based on that). This will allow you, amongst other thing, to see how many different users use your webservice.